# Abaqus VisError - problem with xyDataListFromField

Tags: python, abaqus

I have a python script in Abaqus gui. When I try to run this script I have error: `VisError: No xy data was extracted using the provided options`.

The python script fragment is:

```
 session.viewports['Viewport: 1'].setValues(displayedObject=o3)
session.viewports['Viewport: 1'].makeCurrent()
a = mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly
session.viewports['Viewport: 1'].setValues(displayedObject=a)
session.mdbData.summary()
session.viewports['Viewport: 1'].setValues(
    displayedObject=session.odbs[os.getcwd() + '/' + 'Hotforging1.odb'])
session.viewports['Viewport: 1'].assemblyDisplay.setValues(
    adaptiveMeshConstraints=OFF)
session.linkedViewportCommands.setValues(_highlightLinkedViewports=False)
odb = session.odbs[os.getcwd() + '/' + 'Hotforging1.odb']
session.xyDataListFromField(odb=odb, outputPosition=INTEGRATION_POINT,
                            variable=(('HFL', INTEGRATION_POINT),
                                      ('LE', INTEGRATION_POINT),
                                      ('PE', INTEGRATION_POINT),
                                      ('S', INTEGRATION_POINT),),
                            elementPick=(('HBEAM-1', 4, ('[#0:15 #800 #0:3 #40000000 #900000 ]',)),), )
```

I know that the problem is with `xyDataListFromField` function, but I don't know how can I solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element input for `xyDataListFromField` method is wrong. I think, the input `'[#0:15 #800 #0:3 #40000000 #900000 ]'`, you must have got from `getSequenceFromMask` method. The input for this method is internal, hence you cannot use it in your code. 
Anyways, first of all, I did not find `elementPick` option for this method. However, some alternative option you can use are: `elementSets` and `elementLabels`. 
This information I got from Abaqus Scripting reference Guide:

> *elementSets* 
> A sequence of Strings specifying element sets or a String specifying a single element set.

> *elementLabels* 
> A sequence of expressions specifying element labels per part instance in the
> model. Each part instance element expression is a sequence of a String specifying
> the part instance name and a sequence of element expressions; for example,
> **`(('partInstance1',(1,'7','3:15;3'),), ('partInstance2','8'),))`**. 
> The element expressions can be any of the following: 
> • An Int specifying a single element label; for example, **`1`**.
> • A String specifying a single element label; for example, **`'7'`**.
> • A String specifying a sequence of element labels; for example, **'3:5'** and **'3:15:3'**.

I think, *`elementSets`* option is easy to use, where is just need to provide the element set names.